# Regexp for css definition with specific name in it and value

Tags: css, regex

I have to match all css definitions with name "test" and with color:gray.
For example:

`a.test { color:grey; }` but also `.test { color:grey;}`
or `a.test:affter, a.test { font-size: 10px; color: gray;}`

so it have to take care of multiple `\s\r\n` and others.

What I already got:

```
test(\s|\r|\n|[:a-zA-Z()0-9])*\{([a-zA-Z:,\s\n\r-0-1;]*)color[\s\n\r:]*gray([a-zA-Z:,\s\n\r-0-1;]*)\}
```

but it isn't working in some places: http://regexr.com?32191.

Please help :)

---

## Solution from @nhahtdh, best for me

`\.test[:a-zA-Z()0-9\s.,]*\{[a-zA-Z:,\s0-1;-]*color[\s:]*gray([a-zA-Z:,\s0-1;-]*‌​)\}`

Comment: `\.test[:a-zA-Z()0-9\s.,]*\{[a-zA-Z:,\s0-1;-]*color[\s:]*gray([a-zA-Z:,\s0-1;-]*)\}` http://regexr.com?32194 Add back the capturing groups if you want it, but they don't seem to capture anything useful.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks, You saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: I have doubt that it will work for all CSS, though. It will work with certain subset at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fairly simple one:

```
[^{]*\.test(?:{|[ :.][^{]*{)[^}]*color[ \n\r]*:[ \n\r]*gray *;[^}]*}
```

This should match your specification, but won't catch any CSS errors.

http://regexr.com?321ah

Comment: Does not match `.test {} x .test{color:gray;}` correctly, you wanted a closing curly bracket in the beginning.

Comment: almost - don't work if css is without ";",
corrected: `[^{]*\.test(?:{|[ :.][^{]*{)[^}]*color[ \n\r]*:[ \n\r]*gray *;?[^}]*}`

Comment: Yeah I saw that, wasn't sure if it'd be a problem. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches your test cases.

```
[^\r]*\.test(\s|\r|\n|[:a-zA-Z()0-9])?[^{]*\{([a-zA-Z:,\s\n\r-0-1;]*)color[\s\n\r:]*gray([a-zA-Z:,\s\n\r-0-1;]*)\}
```

http://regexr.com?32197

The issue is way more complex though. There might be arbitrary characters in different context such as urls, filters and so on. As far as you need to match only these very specific cases, it ought to work.

Comment: This will also match `.testass{color:gray;}`, dunno if that's a problem.